# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : org.mockito.MockitoAnnotation.openMocks

Tags: java, maven

I'm using **maven-3.8.1** along with **java -1.8** to construct my spring microservice project. During install, I am getting these errors tracing to all methods of one the classes :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(Ljava/Lang/object;)Ljava/Lang/Autocloseable;
```

I'm also using **mockito 2.15** along with **powermock 2.0** so I know they're compatible with each other.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try lower version of Mockito. On the powermock github page https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions there is stated, that Mockito 2.8.9+ is compatible with PowerMock 2.x, but it also says, that "A lot of issues are not resolved still."

Comment: Why do you need powermock?

Comment: what do you think?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432118/how-to-fix-this-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-java-lang-autocloseable-org